# Keylogger only used when using a specific application

Tags: javascript, vbscript, keylogger

What tools/references should I look at to have a custom made keylogger capture data only when the user is typing into a proprietary corporate application?

Example, when a user is typing in excel nothing happens. When they switch to word, my application realizes this, and captures the data. Please keep in mind that I would like this to work in conjunction with our propriety (and not modifiable) software, so I can not count on the target program to assist in the process.

I plan on writing in VBscript or JavaScript. Only an amateur coder.

I hope that made sense. Open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "Progranametocheck.exe" then
        wscript.echo "Progranametocheck is running"
        wscript.quit
    End If
next
wscript.echo "Progranametocheck is not running"
```

The Code above (VBscript) checks is a program is running, and makes a pop uptelling you if its running or not. To run a program if a program is running replace: "wscript.echo "Progranametocheck is running" with:

```
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""C:\\dir\\logger.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

So all together it becomes:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "Progranametocheck.exe" then
        Set objShell = Nothing
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run("""C:\\dir\\logger.exe""")
        Set objShell = Nothing
        wscript.quit
    End If
next
wscript.echo "Progranametocheck is not running"
```